Azure CLI: How to filter objects server-side, so that only objects containing a non-empty collection is returned?
I want to filter returned objects (appliations), so that only applications with configured client credentials are returned.
I have made multiple attempts, one of which:
az ad app list --show-mine  --filter '~/application?$filter=passwordCredentials/$count ne 0'
I want to use the --filter OData query, as the filtering is performed server-side, in contrast to using --query, which occurs client-side.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http#operators-and-functions-supported-in-filter-expressions
Any ideas?

Note that, filtering on passwordCredentials property is currently not supported. You can apply --filter on few properties that are mentioned in this MS Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#application-properties

Alternatively, make use of this CLI command that filters based on json response of all apps owned by logged in user az ad app list --show-mine --output json | jq '[.[] | select(.passwordCredentials | length > 0)

Thank you, but I would like filtering to take place on the server :) Currently, thousands of objects are returned, which results in a long response time
